# Foundation's data-interchange attribute with large parameter

Tags: image, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

What am I doing wrong with Zurb's Foundation so the `data-interchange` attributes never uses the `large` parameter? (Small and medium cases are fine.)

Here's an [example to demonstrate](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGzbor) this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add [path (large)] after the [medium]